# setup two php versions in a one machine

Tags: php

I was asked in an interview.

How can we set up two different php version ex:php v 5.0 and php v 5.3  in a single machine?

Is it possible to do it with apache?

Thanks

Comment: You can run one trough CGI and second one as a module.

Comment: I'd move to [sf] but frankly the quality of this question is lacking.  If someone wants to edit to improve, flag it to be migrated as well.

Answer (score 4):

1. > Install the 2 php versions to unique paths.
2. > Install 2 apache's each running on a different port
3. > Setup each apache conf to use a different php version